# Is instantiating a type with initial values cheaper than two separate statements?

Tags: c#, .net, variables, optimization, instantiation

If I do:

```
string x = "Whatever";
```

Is that different in ANY way (other than the obvious syntax) to having it split in two lines?

```
string x;
x = "Whatever";
```

**Is the first way just pure sugar?**

I ask because I had a loop:

```
foreach(string s in MyListOfStrings)
{
     string x = Method(s);
}
```

And wondered if and why this was better / faster / cleaner:

```
string x;
foreach(string s in MyListOfStrings)
{
     x = Method(s);
}
```

I'm sure this has already been asked and pored over so if anyone can just point me to a good article / doc that'd be appreciated.

Comment: In case of a reference type it does not matter. In case of a value type it gives two assignments.

Comment: The chances of this being the *critical* part of your application are practically zero. Why do you think it's worth poring over such a thing? And if it did make a difference, you should measure the differences for *your specific situation*.

Comment: In both cases, the compiler and jitter, will essentially optimize this to the same code. [See for your self](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwCwG5lQDMmM6AwugN7Lq2bFYBs6AygC4BOAlgHYDm6ALIBTNgAsA9sAAU7bv3QBPAJQ061JHS2YA7Evya6AXzW0imbEOnKqp7ZjgYAHugC86AEQB1MQEM2wgBuwhweBvZ0WM4w4RHoTqTu3n4BwaEGdtqBvhxCigAyXADObADyAGZyvHxFbug8wgDu6IUlADxRAHzWGYYR5RIcwr4AxmLo0lHotbx5rWWVnNVFqn32GnFaU07E7iLiUtIrsREma9rbeJlaA0Oj45OO0+izggXFC1X8K9fqv9pOSx7USSGTHf7oM5aM5GIA==). In short you should always test your real code and benchmark it if performance matters to you.

Comment: You can always check sharlab, https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyrs4fsJToFkAFAEo2HLhMKkADHQCeAbnETOcugF46AIgDKEALYwMAC2wA7AOZallFVymyEG7QHVjAQwwwAbjCjXlFUDJUgBOQQQ0eWEbCQBfKjigA===

Comment: Obligatory link to this article... https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: Well I guess you could look into the assembly code to see the difference between the two methods. But for the loop part there is a difference in scope for the variable `x`, so it depends on what you need, do you need to access `x` outside your `foreach` or inside is just fine ? Also note that `string` is [immutable](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b1df45/string-is-immutable-in-C-Sharp/).

Comment: Those 2 blocks of code do different things. In the last block, the variable is available outside the loop but not in the other.

Comment: @DavidG in this example with string and loop, they are immutable anyway, which means there will be an allocation either way. So it doesn't matter if its in out

Comment: @MichaelRandall I know, I'm just stating that the blocks aren't equivalent.

Comment: Yeah it's clearly not a critical part of my application, apologies for trying to further my knowledge by asking a global panel of experts. Guess I'll delete this ridiculous question.

Comment: I mean it's obviously not worth knowing or discussing as the lack of comments and answer exemplifies.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I have no idea.

Comment: @jamheadart all things considered, we are all learning. And I think the comments show this as a common yet interesting question and how to work out future questions of similar nature. I see no malice or anyone belittling you or the question. I wouldn't take it to heart. I mean you even have an upvote! win

Comment: I don't understand why this question is closed for "*does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines*". Else we must close every question about code optimization... and there are many.

Comment: @OlivierRogier stackoverflow can be a wierd dynamic sometimes. I see a lot less worthy questions get answered and survive the gauntlet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Writing that:

```
static void Test()
{

  // Simple initialization

  string s1 = "Whatever";

  string s2;
  s2 = "Whatever";

  // Loop optimization

  var list = new List<string>();

  foreach ( string s in list )
  {
    string s3 = Method(s);
  }

  string s4;
  foreach ( string s in list )
  {
    s4 = Method(s);
  }

}

static string Method(string s)
{
  return s + s;
}
```

Results in this IL release code (ILSPy):

```
.method private hidebysig static 
  void Test () cil managed 
{
  // Method begins at RVA 0x34f4
  // Code size 133 (0x85)
  .maxstack 1
  .locals init (
    [0] string s1,
    [1] string s2,
    [2] class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string> list,
    [3] string s4,
    [4] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<string>,
    [5] string s,
    [6] string s3,
    [7] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<string>,
    [8] string s
  )

  // (no C# code)
  IL_0000: nop
  // string text1 = "Whatever";
  IL_0001: ldstr "Whatever"
  IL_0006: stloc.0
  // string text2 = "Whatever";
  IL_0007: ldstr "Whatever"
  IL_000c: stloc.1
  // List<string> list = new List<string>();
  IL_000d: newobj instance void class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>::.ctor()
  IL_0012: stloc.2
  // (no C# code)
  IL_0013: nop
  // foreach (string item in list)
  IL_0014: ldloc.2
  IL_0015: callvirt instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!0> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>::GetEnumerator()
  // (no C# code)
  IL_001a: stloc.s 4
  .try
  {
    IL_001c: br.s IL_0032
    // loop start (head: IL_0032)
      // foreach (string item in list)
      IL_001e: ldloca.s 4
      IL_0020: call instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<string>::get_Current()
      // (no C# code)
      IL_0025: stloc.s 5
      IL_0027: nop
      // string text3 = Method(item);
      IL_0028: ldloc.s 5
      IL_002a: call string ConsoleApp.Program::Method(string)
      IL_002f: stloc.s 6
      // (no C# code)
      IL_0031: nop

      // foreach (string item in list)
      IL_0032: ldloca.s 4
      IL_0034: call instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<string>::MoveNext()
      // (no C# code)
      IL_0039: brtrue.s IL_001e
    // end loop

    IL_003b: leave.s IL_004c
  } // end .try
  finally
  {
    IL_003d: ldloca.s 4
    IL_003f: constrained. valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<string>
    IL_0045: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    IL_004a: nop
    IL_004b: endfinally
  } // end handler

  IL_004c: nop
  // foreach (string item2 in list)
  IL_004d: ldloc.2
  IL_004e: callvirt instance valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<!0> class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>::GetEnumerator()
  // (no C# code)
  IL_0053: stloc.s 7
  .try
  {
    IL_0055: br.s IL_006a
    // loop start (head: IL_006a)
      // foreach (string item2 in list)
      IL_0057: ldloca.s 7
      IL_0059: call instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<string>::get_Current()
      // (no C# code)
      IL_005e: stloc.s 8
      IL_0060: nop
      // string text4 = Method(item2);
      IL_0061: ldloc.s 8
      IL_0063: call string ConsoleApp.Program::Method(string)
      IL_0068: stloc.3
      // (no C# code)
      IL_0069: nop

      // foreach (string item2 in list)
      IL_006a: ldloca.s 7
      IL_006c: call instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<string>::MoveNext()
      // (no C# code)
      IL_0071: brtrue.s IL_0057
    // end loop

    // }
    IL_0073: leave.s IL_0084
  } // end .try
  finally
  {
    // (no C# code)
    IL_0075: ldloca.s 7
    IL_0077: constrained. valuetype [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1/Enumerator<string>
    IL_007d: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]System.IDisposable::Dispose()
    IL_0082: nop
    IL_0083: endfinally
  } // end handler

  IL_0084: ret
} // end of method Program::Test
```

As we can see, there is no difference at all : the code is exactly the same, without considering the NOPs (memory alignment instruction to optimize the CPU thing whose name I forgot that executes the instructions).

For the first thing, I'm ok.

But where I'm disapointed is that for the loop optimization as in C++ I had learned 25 years ago to do that even with compiler optimizations on, that is useless in C# (I had never checked this before).

Comment: Modern C# compiler do the things better than C++ compiler on 1995. No need to declare variable outside loop to optimize : the compiler do that for us now.

Comment: Most optimizations, if they occur, are being done at JIT time. They're not done to the IL.

Comment: I talked about generated IL...

Comment: So, for example [Loop Invariant code hoisting](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/ryujit-overview.md#phases-of-ryujit), what I assume you were disappointed not to see, is part of RyuJit, not the C# compiler.